# react-yandex-maps Placemark balloonContentBody: React component

Tags: reactjs, jsx, yandex-maps

I will try to find help here. I use the reacr-yandex-maps library where when you click on a marker in a pop-up window, you need to render the **React** **component** with your own logic. In the documentation and on the Internet, I did not find a solution to how to transfer JSX markup to it

Sample code:

```
  import MarkerPopupCreateEvent from 'src/client/components/blocks/PopupCreateEvent'

  export default function CreateMarker(props) {
  const { coordinates } = props
  const userProfilesList = useSelector(
    (state) => state.profiles.userProfilesList
  )
  const createdByEmail = useSelector((state) => state.user.email)
  const markerIcon = usersMarkerIcon(userProfilesList, createdByEmail)

  return (
    <Placemark
      geometry={coordinates}
      properties={{
        balloonContentBody: MarkerPopupCreateEvent,
      }}
      options={markerIcon}
      modules={['geoObject.addon.balloon', 'geoObject.addon.hint']}
      children={MarkerPopupCreateEvent}></Placemark>
  )
}
```